# Save to Google drive not working

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on integrating Saving to GDrive in my web app. I have configured it in my local using the below code:

```
<div class="g-savetodrive" data-src="<%=fileUrl%>" data-filename="<%=fileName %>" data-sitename="eKnowledgeHub">                    
</div>
```

In my local, when I select the save option, the document is getting uploaded into my GDrive with a status message that the file has been saved. When I deployed it in our test server (runs on CentOS), the save option is not working.

Though the location in the GDrive was selected, the file doesn't seem to hvae gotten upload and the following message wasn't displaying either.

When tested in the Firefox, it works quite rarely and rest of the times behaves as in Chrome browser. I have attached a snapshot of how the button looks after selecting the location in GDrive.

Status is showing as "Item will be saved to google drive" even after selecting the location and file is not uploading into the GDrive:

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry Halfer, I will make sure it doesn't repeat.

Comment: How are you doing this - deploying on your server? Did you check the full [Save to Drive Button](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive)? Try using the [Upload Files using Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) route.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this change protocol HTTP to HTTPS.